# convert xml to dataframe - duplicate subscripts for columns error

Tags: r, xml, dataframe

I am trying to convert an xml file into a dataframe
The xml file is downloaded from here (for the year 2020)

```
https://prtr.defra.gov.uk/full-dataset

library(XML)

fileName <- file.path(getwd(), 'uk_prtr_dataset_2020.xml')
xmlData <- xmlInternalTreeParse(fileName)

# print xml data
print(xmlData)

# convert xml data into a dataframe
xmlDataFrame <- xmlToDataFrame(xmlData)


Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, names(nodes[[i]]), value = c(NationalID = "Wales_NP3037AF",  : 
duplicate subscripts for columns
```

I am not able to figure out what this error means and any correction to it

Comment: what data/nodes would you want to extract from the xml?

Comment: I am not fully aware of the content of the xml since the goal is to understand the content itself.  so I was thinking of converting everything in the dataframe format and use it for exploration. Sorry if this is not clear.

Comment: By default, XML is incompatible with a table, because some objects can have different properties whereas in a table every object in a row has the same properties (one per column). This might be the reason why the data is not stored in a tabular format. So you need to extract only nodes of the same type to make a data frame out of it,.

Comment: Okay. Is there any way I can get the name of the columns at least so that I can intuitvely decide which column I need to extract

Comment: Open the xml in a suitable reader (I like tu use sublime with the `indent xml` plugin. Do your exploration there, and then use R for parsing the data you need.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will explore that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I went about it after doing some exploration.

```
xml_file <- read_xml(file.path(dir_ls$input, 'raw_data', 'uk_prtr_dataset_2020.xml'))
```

I figured out which columns I need

```
node_vec <- c("ParentCompanyName","FacilityName","LongitudeMeasure","LatitudeMeasure","RiverBasinDistrictID", "MainEconomicActivityName")
```

And then wrote a loop to create a dataframe

```
temp_list <- list()
for(node in seq_along(node_vec)){

  node_ref <- node_vec[node]

  var_ref <- paste0(".//rsm:",node_ref)

  temp <- xml_file %>%   
                   xml_find_all(var_ref) %>%
                   as_list() %>%
                   simplify() %>%
                   enframe() %>%
                   unnest_wider(value) %>%
                   dplyr::select(...1)

 names(temp) <- node_ref

 temp_list[[node]] <- temp
 print(paste0(node_ref,": ",nrow(temp)))
 rm(temp)
}

results <- do.call(cbind, temp_list)
head(results)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is how to get a table containing one address per row:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(xml2)

read_xml("~/Downloads/uk_prtr_dataset_2007.xml") %>%
  xml_find_all(".//rsm:Address") %>%
  as_list() %>%
  simplify() %>%
  enframe() %>%
  unnest_wider(value) %>%
  unnest_wider(CityName) %>%
  unnest(StreetName) %>%
  unnest(StreetName) %>%
  unnest(PostcodeCode) %>%
  unnest(PostcodeCode)

#name StreetName                                                                                    ...1                       PostcodeCode BuildingNumber
#<int> <chr>                                                                                         <chr>                      <chr>        <list>        
#  1     1 "Klondyke Building Cromac Street"                                                             "Belfast"                  BT7 2JA      <NULL>        
#  2     2 "Heriot Watt Research Park, Avenue North, Riccaton"                                           "Edinburgh"                EH14 4AP     <list [1]>    
#  3     3 "Parkway Avenue"                                                                              "Sheffield"                S9 4WF       <list [1]>    
#  4     4 "3 Whitehall Place"                                                                           "London"                   SW1A 2AW     <NULL>        
#  5     5 "All correspondence to: Defra, Industrial Pollution, 5F Ergon House, Horseferry Rd. London. " "East Riding of Yorkshire" SW1P 2AL     <NULL>        
#  6     6 "All correspondence to: Defra, Industrial Pollution, 5F Ergon House, Horseferry Rd. London. " "East Staffordshire "      SW1P 2AL     <NULL>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a good start. There are other field that I am more interested in including: `ParentCompanyName` `LongitudeMeasure`   `LatitudeMeasure`